# Accessing an object's field from within a list

Tags: list, vb.net

I apologize if this is a mislead question, as my major is mechanical engineering and my computer science knowledge is not extensive.

I am trying to access a field/member value of a class that is stored within a "list" object, for use within another object. So far, searches and Intellesense have failed me and I'm lost.

Example:

```vb
Class Dog

   Public FurColor As String = "brown"

End Class
```

I would like to access FurColor in the following way:

```vb
Class MethodsForLotsOfDogs

   Function GetDogColor(dogList As List(Of Dog), dogID As Integer)

      Dim color As String
      color = dogList(dogID).FurColor '<----- Not an actual method for "List" objects
      
      Return color

   End Function

End Class
```

I am trying to find a way to access FurColor from within MethodsForLotsOfDogs. I have a feeling I may be using the "List" object incorrectly, but using a Collection did not seem to provide me with a way to access a public member value either. My real code manages sets of point-to-point stepper motor control profiles (objects) as they (motion settings) are communicated over a serial port, and each set must be iterated through, in order, to complete a motion cycle. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You could iterate over the list, and access the property for each item in the list (or use an `if` condition to find the particular object in the list you want).  Or, use LINQ to locate the object in the list that you want, and then access the property once you have single object. Basically, you can only access the property from the individual object in the list.

Comment: Thank you for the help - would you be able to provide a line of syntax for accessing an item's property? This is the part that I cannot seem to figure out or find any examples of.

Comment: You need to provide a type for the `dogID` argument. Also, **set `Option Strict On`!**

Comment: Looks I slipped up while typing the example code (MATLAB and Python are my daily-drivers) I've added a type to the example. Is there a specific reason I should be using Strict?

Comment: yes... .Net really wants to be type safe, and you'll save yourself all kinds of trouble by giving the compiler the information it needs to do good type checking. You may see more errors up front, but faster code, fewer errors reaching your users, and faster debugging are your rewards.

Comment: [Joel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77129710/2359687) has an example of both approaches I was referring to.  I was under the assumption that `dogID` is the ID property, so it can't be used to reference position.

Comment: Does the real code communicate some identifying information with each packet so you know which profile to access?  You should have spent more time providing a LOT of detail about what you are actually trying to do IMHO.

Comment: Did you try your example code?  It looks to me like it should do what you want.  How did the results differ from what you expected?  The only issue I see with your code is that you didn't declare a return type for the function (it should be declared `As String`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `dogId` is the index within the list, you can do this:

```
Function GetDogColor(dogList As List(Of Dog), dogID As Integer) As String
   Return dogList(dogID).FurColor 
End Function
```

And you won't get an error about calling a method that doesn't exist because the `As Integer` tells the compiler `dogID` can be used as an index instead. In fact, now it hardly even seems worth writing the method ;) But **NEVER** omit type information from your parameter declarations, and **NEVER** omit the return type of a Function — and even better, turn `Option Strict On` at the top of the file.

---

If `dogID` is *NOT* an index lookup, but rather a property to find — say, for a class like this:

```vb
Public Class Dog
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property FurColor As String
End Class
```

Then you would have code like this:

```vb
Function GetDogColor(dogList As List(Of Dog), dogID As Integer) As String
   Return If(dogList.FirstOrDefault(Function(d) d.ID = dogID)?.FurColor, "")
End Function
```

Or like this:

```vb
Function GetDogColor(dogList As List(Of Dog), dogID As Integer) As String
   For Each d As Dog In dogList
       If d.ID = dogID Then Return d.FurColor
   Next
   Return ""
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you! One of my issues seems to be with how I declared my parameters; I apparently used a list()() instead of a list(). I've only been working in VB.NET for about two weeks, so I hadn't noticed. I have also set Strict to on, as you and others have said. This example solved my issue exactly - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

this would be the code to add and retrieve a dog and its coloor

```
    Dim dog1 As New Dog()
    dog1.FurColor = "black"
    Dim list1 As New List(Of Dog)
    list1.Add(dog1)
    Dim fur As String = GetDogColor(list1, 0)
    'returns black
```

You need the class dog

```
Class Dog

    Public FurColor As String = "brown"

End Class
```

The  Function need s areturn value, so you need to add it as return value as as string#

```
Public Function GetDogColor(dogList As List(Of Dog), dogID As Integer) As String

    Dim color As String
    color = dogList(dogID).FurColor 

    Return color

End Function
```